# All Camel routes stop when activemq is not working

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using an xml based camel context having two routes. Route1 reads from a queue in my local activeMQ and Route2 is initiated by a camel timer component and has no reference to the activeMQ.

After starting activeMQ, I started my camel application and both routes worked fine. However, when activeMQ is stopped, both routes stop working.

Since Route2 doesn't have any connection with the activeMQ shouldn't it keep on working? I tried defining the 2 routes in two camel contexts as well but it didn't resolve the issue. Could you please help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- The ActiveMQ connection factory with specification of the server URL -->
    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://tcp://localhost:61616" />
                <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
                <property name="password" value="admin"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myApp" class="org.camel.poc.App"/>
    <bean id="testProcessor" class="org.camel.poc.TestProcessor"/>


  <!-- here is Camel configured with a number of routes -->
  <camelContext id="camel1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="3">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:testMQ"/>
        <!--process ref="myApp"/-->
        <to uri="activemq:queue:testMQDestination2"/>
    </route>

  </camelContext>

  <camelContext id="camel2" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="2">
        <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=5000"/>
        <process ref="testProcessor"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: do you get any Exceptions?

Comment: No I don't see any Exceptions.

Comment: I would recommend to set org.apache.camel to DEBUG and see what it logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `asyncStartListener` option and set it to `true` to startup ActiveMQ async which will allow other routes and Camel to start. See more about this in the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jms

```
<from uri="activemq:queue:testMQ?asyncStartListener=true"/>
```

Comment: I have a question regarding the documentation on asyncStartListener.

That seems to imply that after a while, if the endpoint you’re trying to connect with still isn’t up, you’re going to have to manually restart the route via the JMX interface. Also, looking through the documentation, there doesn’t seem to be a way to set the connection timeout interval.

Is there a way to control how long the route would try to connect before giving up and log an exception, if that happens?